# icontains and query with Umlaut

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

My Product database mostly consists of a number and a json field:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    data        = models.JSONField()
    number      = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

The data attribute looks like:

```
data = {"name": "Würfel", "price": 20,
        "name": "truffels", "price": 1.20, }
```

Now the query:

```
products = Product.objects.all()
r = products.filter(Q(data__icontains = "ürf"))
```

results in an empty query, while

```
r = products.filter(Q(data__icontains = "fel"))
```

gives back results - this happens for all Umlaute. How can I address this?

I face this issue on mariadb.

Comment: What database are you using? I believe SQlite has issues when case-insensitive matching unicode characters

Comment: I am using mariadb - but thanks for the SQLite hint, I also saw it in testing.